# MongoDB ObjectID uniqueness in a Sharded Cluster

Tags: mongodb, objectid

If I have a MongoDB sharded cluster with multiple MongoS instances, will my ObjectID in _id be consistant whichever MongoS I write to?

For example, if I write some data from MongoS#1 and the _id ascends normally, if I then write using MongoS#2 will these _id's also ascend in line with the other writes?

Seeing as part of ObjectID is based on the machine hash and the process id, I can't see that this will so sorting on the ObjectID would be useless. Correct?

Whats the recomendation here?

Comment: Simple answer would be yes. Mongo maintains uniqueness of _id field across sharded cluster.

Answer (score 0):

How the ObjectId is generated would give you a fair idea about your query.

if you type this in your mongo console,

> new ObjectId()

you would see the ObjectId sample value as

```
ObjectId("558bf61f9f49f303f72dd59b")
```

Now, lets break and see how mongo generates this.
    558bf61f 9f49f3 03f7 2dd59b

1. Here the first 8 characters (4 bytes) represents the number of seconds (not milliseconds) as timestamp.
2. the next 3 bytes is the machine identifies.
3. the next 2 bytes are the process id.
4. and lastly the 3-bytes are the random value.

http://api.mongodb.org/libbson/current/bson_oid_t.html

So, for sure however mongos you are connected with, as the time goes on it would be in ascending order only (because of the first point) the other points ensure that its always a unique number. Hope it clarifies your doubt.

-$

Comment: The thing is I don't think it adequately explains how the machine ID and process ID as gained.
Is it from the client app, the mongos process machine, the primary of the shard its written to?

Just wondered if this was addressed in a sharded cluster setup in a different way to keep some consistency.

Comment: true, however, my explanation does answer your question about ascending the primary key (_id). though you can observe if e.g. you run a java program and make bulk inserts then the Machine Id and Process Id across the records are always same, its only the timestamp and random number differs. One observation the processId in the field is NOT the same as of the process id of Java code.

Comment: Okay. I think I will do some experimentation with multiple mongos processes and multiple client connections and see if I can determine where the machineID and processID come from.
The main thing I am trying to achieve here is an accurate way to determine where the last update occured with multiple connections and read onwards from that point. If I could have relied on _id that would have helped but it looks like I will have to find another solution.

Comment: sure, pls update me as well...however, i think if the inserts are done after a second you can always figure out what is the latest one...however, if the inserts are done within seconds then we cannot exactly figure out which of the insert is the latest one because machine id and process id are going to be same and the last char set is the random number. But still if you want to know, you can always add a created_date field and set the value as timestamp.